# General approach to extract key text from sentence (nlp)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Given a sentence like:

```
Complimentary gym access for two for the length of stay ($12 value per person per day)
```

What general approach can I take to identify the word gym or gym access?

Is this a POS tagger for nouns?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most widely used techniques for extracting keywords from text is [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) of the terms. A higher TF-IDF score indicates that a word is both important to the document, as well as relatively uncommon across the document corpus. This is often interpreted to mean that the word is significant to the document.

One other method is using lexical chains. I refer you to this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306457307000398) for full description.

There are many other approaches out there that you can explore to use depending on your domain. A short survey can be found [here](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~pdevineni/papers/Lott.pdf).

Noun POS tags are not sufficient. For your example, "length of stay" is also a noun phrase, but might not be a key phrase.